# SQL: how to get records with a unique column value and sum the values in another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I have this table called `file`

```
id         integer primary key,
created_on timestamp
updated_on timestamp 
file_name  text not null
path       text not null unique
hash       text not null
size       bigint not null
size_mb    bigint not null
```

I want to get all the records with a unique `hash` value (that is a single instance of duplicated files) and then *sum* the values in the `size` column to the total bytes of disk space I'll need to back up a single copy of each file.

Comment: Which flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: basically I don't know how to use DISTINCT in combination with sum.

Comment: I am using postgres

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you thought about getting the distinct values first as a subquery and then summing the values after?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use a sub-query but I can't figure out the correct syntax.  Basically select distinct hash then take those results and sum size

Comment: sounds like a simple `select hash, sum(size) from file group by hash`

Answer (score 1):

This returns only unique hashes, i.e. no duplicates exist:

```
select *, 
   -- group sum of all files
   sum(size) over () 
from
 (
   select *, 
      -- rows per hash
      count(*) over (partition by hash) as cnt
   from file
 ) as dt
where cnt = 1
```

Edit:
This return only one row per hash:

```
select *, 
   -- group sum of all files
   sum(size) over () 
from
 (
   select *, 
      -- unique number per hash
      row_number(*) over (partition by hash order by hash) as rn
   from file
 ) as dt
where rn = 1
```

Both queries are Standard SQL, but PostgreSQL also supports proprietary syntax:

```
select *, 
   -- group sum of all files
   sum(size) over () 
from
 (
   select DISTINCT ON (hash) *
   from file
   order by hash
 ) as dt
```

Comment: this seems to work, but I am skeptical of the results so I am not entirely sure it is working.  
When I sum all the files I get: 2.45268E+13 bytes 23951976814 kb  23390602.36 mb 22842.38511 gb  22.30701671 tb
This query produces 6.45481E+11 630352099.7 kb  615578.2224 mb 601.1506078 gb 0.58706114 tb
I don't think I have 21.5 tb of duplicate files.

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood your request, this return only unique hashes, i.e. no row if multiple exist. I'll edit my query.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for this. I ran each query and got two different results. The first query sums to 644509907755 to .tb of files.

Comment: The second two produce the same results 3218444227145 which is just under 3tb if I did my divide by 1024 correctly (2.927157973) I can imagine that I have 3tb of unique files and lots of dups. Thank you again.

Comment: I had not seen over () or  over(partition) before. Thanks for giving me stuff to learn about.

Comment: The DISTINCT ON doesn't need the ROW_NUMBER (it was a leftover of cut&paste). i edited my answer

Comment: so exported the results into excel and summed the size column expecting the same value as sum column but I got:

excel sum of size 3218440278893.00
SQL generated sum 3218444227145.00

wonder what's up with that.

Comment: Excel does all calculation using FLOAT with 15 digits precision while DBMSes got numerics up to 38 digit precision. But your result got only 13 digits which should be in the range of a float

Comment: so that would explain such a big difference in the end values?

Comment: No, must be something else (although the difference is really not big)